# Best way for overwritting cv::Mat data

Tags: c++, opencv

Currently I have something like this since I failed to find something better doing a quick scan at the OpenCV `Mat` API:

```
cv::Mat frame_mat(width, height, CV_8UC3);

for(;;) {
    // Obtain raw data
    frame_mat = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, raw_data);
    // Use frame_mat
}
```

It doesn't look resource friendly, at a high level it seems to be allocating and freeing memory for a temporary `cv::Mat` object at each iteration, just to set a global one.

How should I set `free_mat` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to allocate anything outside of the loop. Your code should be:

```
for(;;) {
    // Obtain raw data
    Mat frame_mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, raw_data);
    // Use frame_mat
}
```

In this case frame_mat is just a wrapper for your raw_data that allow you to pass it to OpenCV functions. It is not allocating any memory except for a tiny constant size header. It is also not allowed to de-allocate memory that was not allocated by it, so don't forget to release your raw_data at end of the scope.

Also keep in mind that if you change value of pixel in frame_mat, raw_data is changed.

Comment: Indeed, I failed to see the outer variable was useless in this case at last. Also thanks about the other bit of information about deallocation, I didn't know `Mat` was being just as a thin wrapper of my raw data and that I needed to free it (OpenCV beginner).

Answer (score 1):

You could assign each element separately using [`cv::Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) or copy the data for each row using [`cv::Mat::ptr`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr). Make sure to read the documentation, especially for the last one.

Note that these methods may well end up being slower than just creating a temporary (which may even be removed by the compiler when optimizations are turned on).

Comment: I find it difficult to see how optimization would always overwrite `frame_mat` _inner_ data (not just a pointer etc), achieving zero allocation on free storage, which is what I'm after. Here I'm assuming `cv::Mat` is light at the stack, and heavy at the free storage.